# How to Export Huge Table from Azure SQL Database to CSV using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I work on proof of concept of Azure Logic Apps. I have a table with 70 columns and 10 million rows. I use Logic Apps to export data and upload to FTP.

The process works on a small dataset (3000 rows); however, the process fails on the whole table.

I get the error message below:

> BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write
>   more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size:
>   104857600.'

Logic App Steps:

1. Recurrence
2. SELECT statement - failure
3. Create CSV Table
4. Upload to FTP

Please advise. I could use a stored procedure and batch it in 5,000 rows but I'm not sure how to implement it in Logic Apps.

Comment: is your file more tan 50mb at the end ? may be you can trigger a data factory run that will export to csv in a blob storage then upload to ftp ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#ftp-sftp-and-sftp-ssh-limits) documentation, there is a file a HTTP message size limit of 100 MB and a file size limit of 50 MB when processing FTP files. You can use [chunking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages) to workaround those limits, if the connector supports it.